# how to attach mail in my output file using fpdf

Tags: php, html, fpdf

```
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/unwant/test3.pdf";
$filename="test3.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

i got my output file in this code  $pdf->Output($filename,'F'); i want to attach my output file in mail.

Answer (score 0):

```
require('lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', array(500,233));
$pdf->AddFont('Georgiai','','georgiai.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('lib/fpdf/image.jpg',0,0,500);
$pdf->SetFont('georgiai','',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

// email stuff (change data below)
$to = "myemail@example.com"; 
$from = "me@example.com"; 
$subject = "send email with pdf attachment"; 
$message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "test.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

To use PHPMailer:

- Download the PHPMailer script from here:
  http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient
  place in your project.
- Include the main script file --
  require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');

Now, sending emails with attachments goes from being insanely difficult to incredibly easy:

```
$attachment= $pdf->Output('attachment.pdf', 'S');

$mailer->AddStringAttachment($attachment, 'attachment.pdf');
```

Comment: Hi @rajat.gite i need a help in my code to change your code i just try it but it not work please clarify my code    `$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/unwant/test3.pdf";
$pdf->Output($path,'F');`

Comment: @khairuddeen which error do you have? If you go to unwant/* doesn't exist file?